# How to remove tile mortar from painted baseboard?

Tags: removal, thinset

I'm in the process of having a floor re-tiled.  I have noticed that there are several areas where the tiler has splashed thinset mortar onto the painted, contoured baseboard.  In reviewing online I see that the solution typically put forward is to scrap it off with a pallet knife or razorblade. But the examples shown are for a nice smooth baseboard or wall.  Nothing I have seen shows removal from a contoured surface. So what would be the appropriate method in this case?

Here is one of the most egregious splatter examples.  You can also see in this photo that I have textured walls (why did people do this?!?!??!).  There is also the occasional splatter onto the wall surface itself.

[image]

Comment: The tiler should be responsible for clean up.  Would do what you have found(carefully), but for the contoured sections sandpaper on a soft block should work.  Be very careful if using razor blades or sharp hard blades since they can dig into the wood and gouge it.

Comment: The tiler *will* be responsible for cleanup (but let's just say for now that I don't fully trust the tiler).  I'm really trying to get a sense of best practices.  I'd also be concerned about various blades for the reasons you mentioned (which prompted this question) but even with a something like a soft block I'm also concerned about damaging the paint surface and potentially requiring a repaint of the baseboards.

Comment: Think thinset might stain paint if left to dry.  Usually messy jobs should have a wet cloth handy to wipe up stuff on surfaces it is not wanted.

Comment: @crip659 Oh it's dry alright.  Not only has it been like that for over 4 days, I live in an environment where the humidity is typically low (and currently it's 22%).  I agree about the damp cloth though.

Comment: Withhold final payment until the job is done to your satisfaction, including clean up. If he ends up damaging the baseboard, then it's on him to repair/replace, including repainting if necessary. (And oh, how I long for days of living in 22% humidity, it's a nice, "dry" 55% here today...)

Comment: @FreeMan Fortunately I didn't directly hire this tiler, I instead went through a local flooring store (who I am guessing subcontracted the work).  And there is plenty of money to withhold for this and other issues (^*&^%@##%& oil stains on my driveway from his truck).  And my satisfaction could amount to ripping up all 600 sq ft and re-doing it from scratch.

Comment: That will definitely get the flooring company's attention, and probably lose the guy any future contracts with them. Of course, it sounds well deserved.

Comment: I would also suggest withholding, that is just sloppy work that should have been wiped up. If done prior to setting up that would have been fine and not noticeable, now there is no way it can be cleaned up that I know of that wont require paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get an [angled sanding sponge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001RB20BS) and carefully sand it off. Get both a 100-grit and 150-grit and see which one works best.

Once the material has been removed then you'll likely need two coats of paint.

Make sure to take care and not scuff up your new tile while sanding. Not sure how many linear feet you are dealing with but assume you will be donating 6-8 hours of your life to this cleanup.

If you cannot donate such time then do not attempt the cleanup since you could very easily make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

That tiler screwed up. It's so easy to remove with a sponge before it hardens...

You can always try these, sold as "painter's tool"

[image]

The various shapes at the end are great for scraping stuff. Especially the claw at the end is nice to get stubborn stuff out of corners and hard to reach crevices. But that's gonna take a while, and you should definitely not be the one doing it since you're not responsible for that screwup!

As for the textured wall, good luck.

If you plan to put white or light colored grout between these tiles, the tiler will also have to remove all the blobs of gray thinset poking out of the joints. If you plan on dark or grey grout, then it won't be necessary.

These big thick industrial strength abrasive pads work wonders to remove leftover thinset from tiles. I get them at the tile shop. They will also scratch the paint, but it looks like you'll have to do a paint touchup anyway...

[image]